# How to enable /var/log/debug in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, configuration, rsyslog

How to enable debug logging that will be written to in `/var/log/debug`?

There is a piece of configuration related to debug in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`:

```
#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
```

What I've already tried:

1. Uncomment the piece of configuration `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`.
2. Add the uncommented piece of configuration to the `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

After each try I run:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

The `rsyslog` service is restarted in `/var/log/syslog`, however, `/var/log/debug` has not appeared.

Comment: What do you expect? Have you used `logger` (Read `man logger`) to write a `DEBUG` level message to the log? Have you invoked programs with debug options?

Comment: My expectation is that there is a service that writes messages on debug level, that should be written to /var/log/debug once debug level on rsyslog is set. Isn't it valid?

Comment: Read `man 3 syslog`.